# Can andoird bluetooth api scan BLE device when the broadcast channel wasn't at 37,38,39

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I had a Nordic nrf52840 using the example periodic_adv in nrf connect sdk v2.0.0, and I wrote an app using android bluetooth api. I can't find my device, but I can find some device then I look up in wireshark sniffer to check what's the diffrence, I found out that the device I can find broadcast at channel 37,38,39 mine broadcast at 0 to 39, can bluetooth api scan device broadcasting at other channel or it can only find device working at 37,38,39?

```
package com.example.tryble_scanner;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;
private boolean mScanning = false;
private Handler mHandler = null;

private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
                //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();
                Log.d("BLE", btdevice.getAddress());
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.d("BLE", "error");
            }
};
private  ScanCallback mLeScanCallback2=new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.d("BLE","scan stop");
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.d("BLE","stop scan failed");
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void stop_scan(View view) {
    Log.d("Ble","scan stop pressed");
//        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
}

public void onBtnScan(View view) {
    Log.i("Btn","get click");
    checkBTPermission();
    String[] names=new String[]{"Auden test"};
    List<ScanFilter> filters=null;
    if(names != null){
        filters=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name:names){
            ScanFilter filter=new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build();
            filters.add(filter);
        }
    }

    if(mBluetoothLeScanner==null){
        Log.i("BLE","could not get scanner");
    }else{
        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);  
    }
}

private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d("BLE","checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of your code, but could one device use Bluetooth Low Energy and the other Bluetooth Classic?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKotzjan I edit the post so I check the packet on wireshark the other devices I found are also bluetooth low energy

Comment: Well the Bluetooth standard uses channels 37,38,39 for advertisements so that's what you should see. Does your peripheral maybe use Extended Advertising?

Comment: @Emil yes I am using extended advertising can android bluetooth api find extended advertising?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder#setLegacy(boolean) and set it to `false`. That should enable scanning for Extended Advertising packets.

I see that you create a `filters` list that is then never used. If you want to use it, it should be passed into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback) together with your `ScanSettings` that has legacy=false.

Comment: Thanks a lot I can find my device now

Comment: Hi @Emil how can I get the extend advertising data?